# new using rails 4 - ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, devise

I'm using devise and rails 4. I have the following model:

```
class Video
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps

  field :url,                type: String
  field :video_id,           type: String
  field :title,              type: String
  field :description,        type: String
  field :suggested_by_name,  type: String
  field :suggested_by_email, type: String
  field :active,             type: Boolean, default: false

end
```

with the following controller:

```
class Frontend::VideosController < ApplicationController

  before_action :authenticate_user!, only: [:index, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  def index
  end

  def new
    @videos = Video.new
  end

  def create
    if @person = Video.create(params[:video])
      flash.now[:success] = "Thanks for suggest this video"
      redirect_to root_path
    else
      flash.now[:error] = "Impossible to add this suggestion"
      redirect_to new_frontend_video_path
    end
  end

  def edit
  end

  def update
  end

  def destroy
  end

  private
    def video_params
      params.require(:video).permit(:url, :title, :description, :suggested_by_name, :suggested_by_email)
    end

end
```

I'm trying to save a record on my mongodb but I get:

> ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError

So I think I making a mistake with strongparameters, some help please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `create` action change `params[:video]` to  `video_params`:

```
 def create
    if @person = Video.create(video_params)
      flash.now[:success] = "Thanks for suggest this video"
      redirect_to root_path
    else
      flash.now[:error] = "Impossible to add this suggestion"
      redirect_to new_frontend_video_path
    end
  end
```

You should `permit` params, instead `Rails` raise `ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError`.